# Redux state change but react will not Rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know you guy might think the question is duplicated but after I go through everything I found that no one was doing the require like mine, therefore I decided to ask a question here.

I have a component which connected to two redux reducers, reducer1 is to get the data and show in the table. ruducer2 is to post data which help me to edit the particular user from the table which generate from reducer1.

Code

reducer1

```
export default (state = {
error: null,
users: [],
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case reducer_1_SUCCESS:
    console.log("success");
    return {
        users: action.payload
    }
    break;
    case reducer_1_TIMEOUT:
    return {
        error: SESSION_TIMEOUT
    }
    break;
    default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

reducer2

```
export default (state = { error: "", success: "", isSnackbarError: false }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case reducer_2_ERROR:
        console.log("reducer_2_ERROR");
        return {
            error: action.payload,
            success: state.success,
            isSnackbarError: true
        };
    case reducer_2_SUCCESS:
        console.log("reducer_2_SUCCESS");
        return {
            error: "haha",
            success: action.payload,
            isSnackbarError: false
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Connect redux with component

```
 let SignInWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(EnhancedTable);   

  SignInWithStyles = reduxForm({
     validate,
      form: "reducer2From"
  })(SignInWithStyles);

const mapStateToProps = ({ reducer1, reducer2 }) => {
    return {
        reducer1,
        reducer2 
    };
 };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { reducer1, reducer2 }
)(SignInWithStyles);
```

In my component

```
 async componentWillMount() {
        await this.props.reducer1();
    }

     <div>
                <Modal
                    aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                    aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                    <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
                        <Typography variant="title" id="modal-title">
                            Register Package { this.state.username }
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="subheading" id="simple-modal-description">
                            <Paper>
                                <form
                                    className={classes.container}
                                    onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this._handleSubmit)}
                                >
                                    <Field
                                        name="description"
                                        type="text"
                                        id="description"
                                        label="Description"
                                    />
                                    </div>
                                    <Button
                                        className={classes.button}
                                        type="submit"
                                        variant="raised"
                                        color="primary"
                                    >
                                        Go to Reducer2
                                    </Button>
                                </form>
                            </Paper>
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </div>

_handleSubmit = values => {
    this.handleClose();
    this.props.reducer2(values, this.props.history);
};
```

Dispatch action

```
export const reducer1 = () => async dispatch => {
    const query = //some query here;
    const res = await axios.post(
        API_URL,
        JSON.stringify(getBody(query))
     );
     const data = res.response;
    if (data.return[0].message === SESSION_TIMEOUT) {
         console.log("TIME OUT");
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: reducer_1_SUCCESS,
            payload: data.return
        });
     }
};


export const reducer2= (user, history) => async dispatch => {
     const {
         description,
         expiryDay,
         packageList,
         type,
         id
     } = user;

     const query = `query{query here}`;
     const res = await axios.post(API_URL, JSON.stringify(getBody(query)));
     const data = res.return;
     try {
         if (data.return.action) {
             dispatch({
                 type: reducer_2_SUCCESS,
                 payload: "payload test"
             });
         } else {
             // registration fails
            dispatch({
                 type: reducer_2_ERROR,
                 payload: data.return.message
             });
         }
     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
 };
```

### [image]

A modal from the same component will pop out after I click on the "INTO REDUCER 2" button from the table which allow me to edit and submit. Reducer2 will execute after I clicked the submit button. I am sure that reducer is working as my console showed what I have logged. The problem is that my render will not re render therefore I can't get the data that return from reducer2 in my props.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: where are you connect your components ?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: and where are you dispatch your actions ?

Comment: @N.Safi updated in question

Comment: I can't see the moment where you using your actions `reducer1` ans `reducer2`

Comment: oh u want to see that too. wait a sec i will update it again

Comment: question updated. @N.Safi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in your reducers merge your values like this

reducer 1

```
export default (state = {
error: null,
users: [],
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case reducer_1_SUCCESS:
    console.log("success");
    return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload
    }
    break;
    case reducer_1_TIMEOUT:
    return {
        ...state,
        error: SESSION_TIMEOUT
    }
    break;
    default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

reducer 2

```
export default (state = { error: "", success: "", isSnackbarError: false }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case reducer_2_ERROR:
        console.log("reducer_2_ERROR");
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload,
            isSnackbarError: true
        };
    case reducer_2_SUCCESS:
        console.log("reducer_2_SUCCESS");
        return {
            ...state,
            error: "haha",
            success: action.payload,
            isSnackbarError: false
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

There rename

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ reducer1, reducer2 }) => {
    return {
        reducer1Values: reducer1,
        reducer2Values: reducer2 
    };
 };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { reducer1, reducer2 }
)(SignInWithStyles);
```

Comment: It really working. what is going on here? and i found that using this way, in mapStateToProps function, the return value merged together in reducer1 even if i follow the way like urs. reducer2Values still no value in it but merged into reducer1Values. Can you roughly explain the code?

Comment: Yes you merge your props `reducer1` and `reducer2` with mapDispatchToProps, so in your component reducer1 and 2 are functions and not values

Comment: but i am using mapStateToProps here. how come will mapDispatchToProps? sorry for so many questions cause i am so new to this. and what about the ...state in reducer?

Comment: At the and all in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are `props` so if 2 props are the same name they are merge, `mapDispatchToProps` provide dispatch in argument `mapDispatchToProps` provide state, it usefull to read the redux tutorial https://redux.js.org/basics

Comment: thx man. actually i went through a lot of online tutorial. everyone was having different method.

Comment: hi nsafi. i found a problem today which is if i click the button for the 2nd time, redux reducer wont re render. anywhere that i can trick redux reducer?

Comment: @DaveCruise may be you erase your store or another reason ... I think you should really read the redux tutorial